# Pandoc replace string with table using Lua filter

Tags: filter, lua, pandoc

In my document I have a placeholder string like:

```
{{changelog}}
```

And would like to replace this with a Markdown formatted table using a Lua filter, the following Lua filter works if I use HTML:

```lua
local string = [[
| some | table |
|------|-------|
| val1 | val2  |
]]

string = [[
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>val1</td>
        <td>val2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
]]
function Para(elem)
    if elem.content[1].text == "{{changelog}}" then
        return pandoc.RawBlock('html', string)
      else
        return elem
      end
end

return {{ Para = Para }}
```

Now this works using the HTML content of variable `string` but how do I get it to work with Markdown formatted content in variable `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return an arbitrary format instead of HTML, we must instruct pandoc to parse the string with `pandoc.read`:

```lua
function Para(elem)
  if elem.content[1].text == "{{changelog}}" then
    return pandoc.read(tblstring, 'html').blocks
  end
end
```

The `pandoc.read` function takes a string and parses it into a pandoc document, where the second argument is the format; we need to use access the documents `blocks` since we are not interested in the metadata.

I've omitted the `return elem`, as pandoc keeps the original element if the function does not return a value.

The alternative would be to construct the table using functions like `pandoc.Table` or `pandoc.utils.from_simple_table`, but that's usually more work.

Also note that `string` is the global used for Lua's string library, so best to chose a different name for the table HTML.

Comment: with the following lua filter:
`local tblstring = [[
    | some | table |
    |------|-------|
    | val1 | val2  |
    ]]

function Para(elem)
    if elem.content[1].text == "{{changelog}}" then
        return pandoc.read(tblstring, 'html').blocks
    end
end

return {{ Para = Para }}
`

and command `pandoc test.md -f markdown --lua-filter=test.lua -t html` will result in the following output: `| some | table | |------|-------| | val1 | val2 |`

the markdown tblstring is not converterd to html

Comment: Use 'markdown' instead of 'html' as the second argument to read if you are passing Markdown input. Also, make sure the table in tblstring is not indented, or it will be read as a codeblock.